# My Retrofit en-queue failing every time

Tags: android, retrofit

i have a Retrofit service which is calling the following API http://api2.bigoven.com/recipe/1962911?api_key=my_api_key

this is my Retrofit Singleton Interface

```
public interface RecipeAPI {    
String BASE_URL = "http://api2.bigoven.com/";
@GET("recipe/{id}")
Call<Recipe> getRecipe(@Path("id") int ID,
                       @Query("api_key") String apiKey);
class RecipesFetcher{
    private static RecipeAPI service;
    public static RecipeAPI getInstance(){
        if (service==null) {

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build();
            service = retrofit.create(RecipeAPI.class);
            return service;
            } else {
                return service;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the Full logcat:

http://codepad.org/lP1AhHCK

this is where i use the Retrofit interface but it always executes onFailure :

```
RecipeAPI.RecipesFetcher.getInstance().getRecipe(recipeID,API_KEY).enqueue(new Callback<Recipe>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Recipe> call, Response<Recipe> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                   //some code    
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(RecipeActivity.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Recipe> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(RecipeActivity.this, "Check your Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

i tried to get `call.toString()`
it give me this message`retrofit2.executorcalladapterfactory$executorcallbackcall@428dc288`

what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: share the  logs.

Comment: @Rockney i want to know why the service fail

Comment: @DeepanshuHarbola here's the full logcat
http://codepad.org/lP1AhHCK

Comment: Where in the question are you trying to use this interface or call enqueue? We can't say why something isn't working if we can't see it

Comment: @cricket_007 i added the logcat to the questions
when am calling enqueue

Comment: Do your Toast methods do anything?

Comment: Do your Toast methods do anything? Did you try to print the Throwable message? "Check your internet" is not very descriptive, and you ignore the actual error

Comment: well it wasn't but i did print the Throwable message , and i finally figured out why 
well , it was from my model classes which was automatically generated by some tool

Comment: @cricket_007 my problem is fixed and i can't thank you enough

Comment: Welcome. Always good to check the actual errors

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to provide the endpoint documentation (the contract).

Should you be providing the API key in the header?

If you shouldn't, have you checked that the API key isnt null?

--edit--
Could you change the protocol to https?

The below docs mention that you are required to use https instead of http.
http://api2.bigoven.com/web/documentation/authentication-process

Comment: here's the doc http://api2.bigoven.com/web/documentation/recipes

yes i checked that it's not null